# How to stop API GET request once data is fetched successfully

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack

My question is strictly related to MEAN stack. I want to fetch the total count of documents stored in my MongoDB databse. My express server is working fine but on postman I can see still it is still making request even though i got correct count on console:

[image]

Here is my code:

**api.js**

```
const uri = 'mongodb://tanzee.......ue&w=majority'
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

router.get('/totalmovies', function(req, res) {
    run().catch(console.dir);
});

async function run() {
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db("mycollection");
      const movies = database.collection("movies");
      const estimate = await movies.estimatedDocumentCount();
      console.log(`Estimated number of documents in the movies collection: ${estimate}`);
    } finally {
      await client.close();
    }
}
```

I took help from the official doc of mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/count/

Output:

> (node:15511) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

> Estimated number of documents in the movies collection: 80

I'm new to this stack. Once the output is fetched, my code should stop the GET call immediately. Please point out my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, the request is pending as you are not sending any response thats why the requester is still waiting to receive one. A simple fix is to send data back to the requester.

```
router.get('/totalmovies', async function(req, res) {
    const result = await run();
   // check how are you getting result when it is a success/failure
   // apply condition same in the below if/else 
   // it just for reference, it might be correct though
    if (result > 0) {
       res.status(200).send(result); 
    } else {
       res.status(404).send({'No Data in DB'});
    }     
});
```

> (node:15511) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
> deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
> parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

for this to work:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

Don't close and rebuild the connection for every request:

```
async function run() {
    try {
      await client.connect();
      const database = client.db("mycollection");
      const movies = database.collection("movies");
      const estimate = await movies.estimatedDocumentCount();
      console.log(`Estimated number of documents in the movies collection: ${estimate}`);
      return estimate;
    } catch (e){
        console.error('Error in fetching the data from DB')
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking into it. Let me test this quickly

Comment: Yes, you can check and let me know if throws an error.

Comment: program enters into else block hence i'm getting `'Error while fetching data'`. I'm now returning `return estimate` from `function run()`.

Comment: I have made a change please check now, yes it was not returned and now the result is only a number not an array.

Comment: Yes, bingo. I made the same changes here after i realized its not an array. `result` is the correct output i.e. count already,. This is what I wanted. :-)

Comment: BTW you solved my other issue also. That deprecation warning. :-)

Comment: Yes, that why we are here buddy to solve each other's problem :).

Comment: But now i'm getting this also `express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead routes/api.js:36:24
(node:19479) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 80`

Comment: i think i should change it to string. Something like `res.status(200).send(""+result);` or else it will be treated a s an error code.

Comment: You can check [this](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.status). If you face any issues, you are open to log a new question and can be assisted.

Comment: thanks for the link. for now `res.status(200).send(""+result);` is working.